# rotate a button with android:rotation xml

Tags: android

I want a button(as an image) to rotate clockwise just for UI. I dont want to rotate the button onClick. Just rotate in xml file is enough. android:rotation does not work for me.

my code is

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:rotation="-90"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_gravity="right|left"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<rotate android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="600"
    android:repeatMode="restart"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/cycle_interpolator"/>

</set>
```

Clock wise – use positive toDegrees value

Anti clock wise – use negative toDegrees value

Comment: thanks this helps.. i can't vote up since my reputations are low

Comment: Hi everyone, @PPD can you please tell where this code should be put?

Comment: @FredMaggiowski put it under res/anim folder.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply rotate a button with the following code inside your button OnClick:
**ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v, "rotation", 0, 360).start();**
Here, 'v' is the button view. Here is an example:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v, "rotation", 0f, 360f).start();     
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: OP asks how to rotate a View using XML. Your approach does not use XML. So this post does not answer the question

Answer (score 1):

Make an XML file suppose rotation.xml and put it in a folder named  anim (in res)

Open that file and write this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rotate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite" //you can change it according to the duration you want it ti rotate
    android:duration="1200" />
```

Then in your code do this in OnCreate:

```
button.startAnimation( 
    AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, R.anim.rotation) );
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: i want to see the design everytime live. so adding animation in runtime cant help

Comment: It will do what you want.